# How to use generic keys for `Setter` arguments in Solid JS?

Tags: typescript, solid-js

I have a from component:

```js
const [form, setForm] = createSignal({
  username: '',
  password: ''
});

return (
  <div class='login'>
    <h1>Login</h1>
    {form().username}, {form().password}
    <form onSubmit={login}>
      <InputText
          form={form}
          setForm={setForm}
          name='username'
          type='text'
          label='Username'
          value={form().username}
      />
      <InputText
          form={form}
          setForm={setForm}
          name='username'
          type='text'
          label='Username'
          value={form().password}
      />
    </form>
  </div>
);
```

And I have an `InputText` component like so:

```js
export default function InputText(props: {
  id: string | null;
  form: Accessor<any>;
  label: string;
  setForm: Setter<any>;
  name: string;
  type: string;
  value: string;
}) {
  const handleInput: JSX.EventHandler<HTMLInputElement, InputEvent> = (
    event
  ) => {
    if (event.currentTarget.name) {
      props.setForm({
        ...props.form(),
        [event.currentTarget.name]: event.currentTarget.value
      });
    }
  };

  return (
    <label>
      {props.label}:
      <input
        id={props.id || props.name}
        type={props.type}
        value={props.form().username}
        name={props.name}
        oninput={handleInput}
      />
    </label>
  );
}
```

But I get the following type error from typescript compiler on `setForm={setForm}`;

```js
Type 'Setter<{ username: string; password: string; }>' is not assignable to type 'Setter<any>'.ts(2322)
InputText.tsx(7, 3): The expected type comes from property 'setForm' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { id: string | null; form: Accessor<any>; label: string; setForm: Setter<any>; name: string; type: string; value: string; }'
```

I would like to use any string value as a key in my `setForm` function so that I can pass input names as keys and input values as values directly?

```js
setForm(prev => ({ ...prev, [name]: value }))
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of `Setter<any>` use `Setter<{ [name: string]: string }>` so that it matches the form of values that can be accepted by Setter

```js
export default function InputText(props: {
  id?: string;
  form: Accessor<any>;
  label: string;
  setForm: Setter<{ [name: string]: string }>;
  name: string;
  type: string;
  value: string;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Component` generic from SolidJS to annotate the component:

```js
import { Component, createSignal, JSX, Setter } from "solid-js";

const InputText: Component<{
  name: string,
  value: string;
  setForm: Setter<Record<string, string>>
}> = (props) => {
  const handleInput: JSX.EventHandler<HTMLInputElement, InputEvent> = (
    event
  ) => {
    const { name, value } = event.currentTarget;
    props.setForm(prev => ({ ...prev, [name]: value }));
  };

  return (
    <input
      name={props.name}
      value={props.value || ""}
      oninput={handleInput}
    />
  );
};

export const App = () => {

  const [form, setForm] = createSignal<Record<string, string>>({
    username: "",
    password: "",
  });

  return (
    <form>
      <InputText
        name='username'
        value={form().username}
        setForm={setForm}
      />
      <InputText
        name='password'
        value={form().password}
        setForm={setForm}
      />
    </form>
  );
};
```

`Setter<{ [key: string]: string >` is OK, alternatively you can use `Record` generic which offers additional benefits.

Check out the example form the official documentation:

```js
interface CatInfo {
  age: number;
  breed: string;
}
 
type CatName = "miffy" | "boris" | "mordred";
 
const cats: Record<CatName, CatInfo> = {
  miffy: { age: 10, breed: "Persian" },
  boris: { age: 5, breed: "Maine Coon" },
  mordred: { age: 16, breed: "British Shorthair" },
};
 
cats.boris;
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type

By using `Record` for the signal's type, you can make everything generic all the way.

Now you will get auto completion for the value property of the `InputText` component, like so `value={form().username}`.

In your implementation `form` prop is redundant. `id` is also not necessary if you are not using it for some other purpose like querying input elements from outside the component.

The `type` property is useful only if `InputText` is used for numeric values however it is better to have a separate numeric input component because `currentTarget.value` will be a string and you will need to convert it into number. So, through a dedicated component you will have less clutter in your component logic. Plus, you can take advantage of additional properties that is applicable to numbers only like `min`, `max` and `step`.

Also you can use object destructuring inside the event handler to avoid repetion:

```js
const handleInput: JSX.EventHandler<HTMLInputElement, InputEvent> = (
  event
) => {
  const { name, value } = event.currentTarget;
  props.setForm({ [name]: value });
};
```